# Are there desktop 3.5mm jacks that can interface with smartphone TRRS headsets?

Tags: headset, connector

The [TRRS jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Mobile_phones) is a recent modification of the 3.5mm audio connector which allows microphone data as well as control signals to be passed from the headset to the device.

However, this standard does not seem to be usable on 3.5mm jacks on desktop computer motherboards. [On a number of tablet-notebooks](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2014/03/07/headset-jacks-on-newer-laptops/), I have noticed that the 3.5mm jack works to control the playback of audio, but I have not ever had one of these headsets work on desktops as a headset device.

Are there any desktop based 3.5mm jacks that support the usage of Android/Apple headsets microphones/control signals?

Comment: @random doesn't this question fall under the "try asking how to find out what suits your needs" exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Apple computers (Both Laptop and Desktops) for the last few years have been able to use iPhone standard (CTIA Standard LRGM TRRS) headsets, with remotes even, for audio in and out.

[Apple Support: How to use Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201919)

> **Which Apple computers work with the microphone and volume controls that are included with the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic?**
>
> Any computer that displays "External microphone" in the System Profiler will work with the Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic.  To confirm that External microphone is in your System Profiler, choose About This Mac from the Apple () menu and then click More Info.  Select Audio (Built In) under the Hardware section.

Note, it's only supported in OSX, not Bootcamp/Windows, AFAIK.

Any computer with USB 3 Type-C connector could/should possibly support it as well.

> The USB Type-C Cable and Connector Specification Revision 1.1 specifies a mapping from a USB Type-C jack to a 4-pole TRRS jack, for the use of headsets, and supports both CTIA and OMTP (YD/T 1885-2009) modes. See Audio Adapter Accessory Mode (Appendix A):
>
> Analog audio headsets are supported by multiplexing four analog audio signals onto pins on the USB Type-C connector when in the Audio Adapter Accessory Mode. The four analog audio signals are the same as those used by a traditional 3.5 mm headset jack. This makes it possible to use existing analog headsets with a 3.5 mm to USB Type-C adapter. The audio adapter architecture allows for an audio peripheral to provide up to 500 mA back to the system for charging.

(Side note, many flavors of Linux now support TRRS headsets, if the hardware it's on support it as well.)

Comment: Also, most Windows tablets and convertibles tend to support some form of control. Unfortunately, (a) it depends a fair bit on the OEM, and (b) most laptops and desktops don't seem to have that capability yet.

Answer (score 2):

As the jack/connection is dependent on the laptop having the correct 3.5mm connector (internal) wiring & logics, it will need to be a specific PC model (advertising that this is fully 4-pole compatible) and not just any device.

That said, if you have a laptop that has inputs for both head-phone-speaker (3.5mm) & microphone (3.5mm) connectors, **you could try a - [4-Pole] TRRS to 3.5mm Stereo & Mic Splitter (Female to 2 x Male)**. This allows you to insert your smartphone headset into the (female) 3.5mm connector, which then splits out to two 3.5mm (male) inputs to your laptop/computer.

[image]

I don't think you will get much more than that out of it (eg. speaker & mic), as the functions of say "music" pause/forward/reverse, etc are more logic programming interpretations that the device carries out based on the signal being received through the 3.5mm connection.